# Hello I need help interpreting results from a sample taken in garage ceiling

Tags: asbestos

[image]Hello I need help interpreting results from a sample taken in garage ceiling. The gypse was covered with a cement coating . The results I will post indicate less than 1% Actinolite. What does this mean . Is it safe to leave or dangerous [image]

Comment: Does the company who provided the results not offer an interpretation or suggestion?

Comment: At less than 1% even with the my state's new laws for transfer stations the material can be dumped. More than 1% has to be taken directly to the landfill. Even straight asbestos material when encapsulated with paint is safe to leave in place.